# How do you change the default axis labels in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using Mike Bostock's [Inline Labels chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4b66c0d9be9a0d56484e), and I have successfully adapted the x axis labels to the proper format for my needs.

However, I'm using only months in the dates and it's displaying 1900 instead of January at the first tick.  I'm assuming as the default year for d3, since I have no need to provide or define one.

I realize now it would probably have been easier to change the scale to use text items, but since this is where I'm at and now I'm curious: how can I correct this formatting with the dates?

I've tried using this code for the .tickValues, but it didn't seem to make a difference:

```
.tickValues(x.ticks(12).concat( x.domain() ));
```

Is there another way to control the values scaleTime displays? Or to format the dates so that it doesn't try to substitute a year for January?

[Here is a jsFiddle of my current code and results.](https://jsfiddle.net/jrf3uux8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing your values using only the abbreviated month name. If you don't specify a year, it defaults to 1900.

Let's proof that:

```js
console.log("A date without year: " + d3.timeParse("%b")("Jan"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

So, that `1900` is expected.

**Solution**: if you want to make sure that the axis only shows the full month name, use `tickFormat` with the correct specifier:

```
.tickFormat(function(d){
    return d3.timeFormat("%B")(d)
})
```

Here is your updated code:

```css
text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.label {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.label rect {
  fill: white;
}

.label-key {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%b");

  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 30
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    labelPadding = 3;

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var data = [{
    date: 'Jan',
    2017: 130,
    2016: 40,
    2015: 140
  }, {
    date: 'Feb',
    2017: 137,
    2016: 58,
    2015: 120
  }, {
    date: 'Mar',
    2017: 166,
    2016: 97,
    2015: 140
  }, {
    date: 'Apr',
    2017: 154,
    2016: 117,
    2015: 40
  }, {
    date: 'May',
    2017: 179,
    2016: 98,
    2015: 110
  }, {
    date: 'Jun',
    2017: 187,
    2016: 120,
    2015: 140
  }, {
    date: 'Jul',
    2017: 189,
    2016: 84,
    2015: 30
  }, {
    date: 'Aug',
    2017: 137,
    2016: 58,
    2015: 50
  }, {
    date: 'Sep',
    2017: 166,
    2016: 97,
    2015: 55
  }, {
    date: 'Oct',
    2017: 154,
    2016: 117,
    2015: 80
  }, {
    date: 'Nov',
    2017: 179,
    2016: 98,
    2015: 40
  }, {
    date: 'Dec',
    2017: 187,
    2016: 120,
    2015: 140
  }];

  data.columns = ["date", "2017", "2016", "2015"]


  data.forEach(d => {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    for (var k in d)
      if (k !== "da") d[k] = +d[k];
  });



  var series = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(key) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: key,
        date: d.date,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  });

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date])
    .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(series, function(s) {
      return d3.max(s, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.timeFormat("%B")(d)
      }));

  var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
    .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "serie");

  serie.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return z(d[0].key);
    })
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      }));

  var label = serie.selectAll(".label")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
    });

  label.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .filter(function(d, i) {
      return i === data.length - 1;
    })
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("class", "label-key")
    .text(function(d) {
      return " " + d.key;
    });

  label.insert("rect", "text")
    .datum(function() {
      return this.nextSibling.getBBox();
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x - labelPadding;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - labelPadding;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return d.width + 2 * labelPadding;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return d.height + 2 * labelPadding;
    });

</script>
```